# Onclick form submit using mootools

Tags: jquery, mootools

I am using JQuery onclick submit event like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    $('#form').submit();
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

I want to do it with mootools.

**Thanks**

Comment: See the Mootools documentation: http://mootools.net/docs/core

Comment: And more specifically, `addEvent`: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event

Comment: Other than that, please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

Using mootools addEvent

```
 $('button').addEvent('click', function(){
        $('form').submit();            
    });
```

Comment: no need to return false. first off, form.submit will go to another url (unless you have a submit event handler that kills the default event). otherwise, if you want to disable the default event action, then change the callback to pass on the event:`...click": function(e) { e.stop(); // stop the click from doing anything first ...`

Answer (score 0):

If `#button` is a submit, you can always do the following:

```
$('form').addEvents({
    submit: function(){
        this.submit();
    }
});
```